# Using SetDiff for a list of vectors and An Anonymous Function

Tags: r

I'm trying to work R's new anonymous functions, and am having some trouble applying `setdiff` to a list of vectors. So for example, creating two vectors and using `setdiff` is usually pretty straightforward:

```
vec_one <- c("this", "is", "a", "test", "vector")
vec_two <- c("this", "is", "also", "a", "test", "vector")
setdiff(vec_one, vec_two)
setdiff(vec_one, vec_two)

character(0)

setdiff(vec_two, vec_one)
[1] "also"
```

When I make a list out of the vectors and use lapply as such, I am getting an error about the second argument:

```
 lapply(list(vec_one, vec_two), \(one, two) setdiff(x = one, y = two))

 Error in as.vector(y) : argument "two" is missing, with no default
```

Any help would be much appreciative! :)

Comment: Use`Map( \(one, two) setdiff(one, two), vec_one, vec_two)` if you want to iterate over pair of lists element-wise. However, the lengths of the two lists need to be the same.

Comment: This would work in the above context: `Map(\(a, b) setdiff(a, b), list(vec_one), list(vec_two))
[[1]]
character(0)`